# iOS lock specific ViewController to specific orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rotation

I want to lock the device's orientation in a specific ViewController to only portrait but none of the available solutions are working. It is embedded in a UINavigationController.

I deployed it to iOS7 and in the general settings, both landscape and portrait are checked because I want it to rotate for other VCs other than the specific one.

```
extension UINavigationController {
public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate()
}

public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return visibleViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
}
}
```

this portion of the code is in my ViewController class

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"In iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated" (See documentation on UIViewController). This could be why it isn't working for you.

I am thinking that Apple has done this to keep the users' experience more consistent throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem which is since I am using SWRevealViewController, the parent VC overrides the subview's rotate settings.

Thus I just subclass it and adjust the autorotate and orientation settings as intended.